# Search and delete links in markdown files

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, loops, markdown

I run from time to time a linkchecker over my site and the external links 404 will be saved to a logfile.

Now I try to delete the links automated from the markdown files. I use multilingual websites so I start read in the logfile to an array.

```
IFS=$'\n'
link=( $(awk '{print $7}' $ext) )

for i in "${link[@]}"; do
    grep -r $i content/* | sed -e 's/([^()]*)//g' 
done
```

This command deletes the link and title with () but the [Example Text] remains. I search for a way to remove [] so that at the end I only get Example Text.

Now:

```
[Example Text](http://example.com "Example Title")
```

Desired result:

```
Example Text
```

Comment: Please include an example of the expected output to help clarify the problem

Comment: The goal is delete all expect Example Text.

Comment: add the expected output.

Comment: What's in `$ext`? Why do you run this in a loop? Tangentially see also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Assumptions

- The `i` in `for i in "${link[@]}"` will evaluate to be a link like "`http://example.com`" each loop
- The format of every section in your markdown file we care about will take on the form you described `[Example Text](http://example.com "Example Title")`

### The code

```sh
IFS=$'\n'
link=( $(awk '{print $7}' $ext) )

for i in "${link[@]}"; do
    grep -ro "\[.*\].*${i}" content/* | grep -o '\[.*\]' | tr -d '[]'
done
```

### Explanation

- `grep -ro "\[.*\].*${i}" content/*`:
- - **Recursive** search to run on all files in a dir: `grep -r ... content/*`
- - Print **only** the text that applies to our regex: `grep -o`
- - Print anything that starts with `[` followed by anything `.*` then a `]` followed by the value of our loop variable `${i}` (The current link): `"\[.*\].*${i}"`
- From that output all we want is `"Example Text"` which lives between the brackets, so anything not between brackets needs to go `grep -o '\[.*\]'`
- Finally, we want to remove those pesky brackets: `tr -d '[]'`

Answer (score 1):

The immediate fix is to extend your `sed` regex.

```
sed 's/\[\([^][]*\)\]([^()]*)/\1/g'
```

But probably a much better fix is to replace all the lines from the Awk script in `content` in a single go.

```
find content -type f -exec \
    sed -i 's%\[\([^][]*\)\('"$(
        awk 'NR>1 { printf "\|" }
            { printf "%s", $7 }' "$ext")"'\)%\1%g'
```

The Awk script produces a long regex like

```
http://one.example.net/nosuchpage\|http://two.exampe.org/404\|https://three.example.com/broken-link
```

from all the links in the input, and the `sed` script then replaces any links which match this regex in the parentheses after the square brackets. (Maybe you'll want to extend this to also permit a quoted string after the link before the closing round parenthesis, like in your example; I feel I am already quessing too many things about what you are actually hoping to accomplish.)

If you are on a *BSD platform (including MacOS) you'll need to add an empty string ar[ument after the `-i` argument, like `sed -i '' 's%...`

Comment: This will remove other non-linked markdown as well, for example [username](mention:[uid])

Comment: @OliverDixon Not sure what you mean? Your example is not valid Markdown. (The script had a couple of pesky typos which I fixed now, though. I guess I must have written it on mobile originally.)